# How do I set the alpha of all items in a listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

As I am developing for API level 7 and upwards `setAlpha(float)` is unavailable to me. As such I have implemented a method that traverses all child elements of a given `ViewGroup` and tries to find a way to set the alpha so that the element is almost transparent. Unfortunately I cannot come up with a way to make the `ListView` and its items transparent. How do I proceed?

My method:

```
public void enableDisableViewGroup(ViewGroup viewGroup, boolean enabled) {
    int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);

        view.setEnabled(enabled);
        if (!enabled) {
            if (view instanceof TextView) {
                int curColor = ((TextView) view).getCurrentTextColor();
                int myColor = Color.argb(ALPHA_NUM, Color.red(curColor),
                        Color.green(curColor),
                        Color.blue(curColor));

                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(myColor);
            } else if (view instanceof ImageView) {
                ((ImageView) view).setAlpha(ALPHA_NUM);
            } else if (view instanceof ListView) {
                // How do I set the text color of the subitems in this listview?
            } else {
                try {
                    Paint currentBackgroundPaint =
                            ((PaintDrawable) view.getBackground()).getPaint();
                    int curColor = currentBackgroundPaint.getColor();
                    int myColor = Color.argb(ALPHA_NUM, Color.red(curColor),
                            Color.green(curColor), Color.blue(curColor));
                    view.setBackgroundColor(myColor);
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    Log.d("viewNotFound", "View " + view.getId() + " not found..");
                    e.getStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
                enableDisableViewGroup((ViewGroup) view, enabled);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your lsitview's adapter code.  You will want to be able to do this sort of thing there as the adapter handles your listviews children.

Comment: There's not a lot to see. listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it an option to set this directly in the XML for your `ListView` row?

For example, if your layout is a `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <!-- stuff -->
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure of your setup, but you may be able to set it programatically like this if you really want your `ListView` to be transparent.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) view;
listView.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
```

where default color `android.R.color.transparent` equals:

```
<!-- Fully transparent, equivalent to 0x00000000 -->
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

In this case, you'll need to set your `ListView` rows to be transparent in the XML anyway.

If you want to control the transparency of the `View`s inside your `ListView` rows, your best bet is to create a custom `ArrayAdapter` and handle this there.

Comment: How would the background color of the listview affect the textcolor of the TextViews in subitems?

Comment: I guess I'm confused on what you're looking for. Can you set the background of all of your sub-items to be transparent in the XML to be that way always?

Comment: I ended up handling setting the alpha of my TextViews in a custom adapter.